# Vimeo JavaScript API add event listener to all iframes on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, vimeo, froogaloop

Been messing around with [Froogaloop](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript), Vimeo's JavaScript API, and am trying to add a class to the Vimeo iFrame that is currently playing. Seems simple enough, using the API's events, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Here's what I've got so far:

The code below is a simplified version of [their example](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api). While it's not causing any errors in my console, I'm not getting any of the logs (and therefore not getting the classes). Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

```
var iframe = $('article.video iframe')[0],
    player = $f(iframe);

player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('play', on);
    player.addEvent('pause', off);
    player.addEvent('finish', off);
});

function on(id) {
    console.log('playing');
    player.addClass('playing');
}
function off(id) {
    console.log('not playing');
    player.removeClass('playing');
}
```

UPDATE

---

The issue definitely has to do with the variables. `Player` tells Froogaloop which iframe to work with, `iframe` identifies which html object that is. So I suppose the issue is how I can identify all the iframes on the page and then feed Froogaloop the appropriate iframe when one is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as I see, in the on() and off() functions Froogaloop is giving you the ID of the iframe by parameter. So, in that case you should add and remove class like this:

```
$('#'+id).addClass('playing');

$('#'+id).removeClass('playing');
```

And in your HTML you should provide an id="videoX" to every iframe tag, plus to add &player_id=videoX at the end of the url address of the src property from the iframe.